# Create a PSCredential with empty username

Tags: powershell

I need to create a PSCredential with an empty username.

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String 'a'
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName PSCredential -ArgumentList '', $Password
```

When I run the above code, I get an exception.

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot process argument because the value of argument 
>   "userName" is not valid. Change the value of the "userName" argument and run the operation again."

How can I create a PSCredential with an empty username, and only have a password?

Comment: You must provide a username when creating a `PSCredential` object. You can provide something like a single space for the username, but `$null` or an empty string are not valid.

Comment: I'am a bit curious, why, do you need credential with an empty username ?

Comment: it wont work. pscredential requires a username and password. the username can not be blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered (and as [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) notes in a comment on the question), you cannot directly provide an empty username (empty string or `$null`) to [the `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]` constructor that accepts username and password *separately*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms567279(v=vs.85).aspx).

You can work around that problem by using [the constructor that accepts a `[psobject]` instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn472912(v=vs.85).aspx), by passing a *custom object* (`[pscustomobject]` instance) with `UserName` and `Password` properties (PSv3+):

```
$Credential = New-Object PSCredential -ArgumentList ([pscustomobject] @{ 
  UserName = '';
  Password = (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String 'a')[0]
})
```

<sup>Note the `[0]` applied to the result of the `ConvertTo-SecureString` call, which is required for the output object to be properly recognized as a `[securestring]` (`[System.Security.SecureString]`) instance (this trick is *not* needed if you use an intermediate variable, as in the question). I'm not exactly sure why this is necessary; perhaps the output is by default treated as a *collection* here; if you know specifically, do tell us.</sup>

**Caveats**:

- Given that the two constructor forms set the *same* data fields, the ability to set an empty username with the object-based constructor could be a *bug* that may get fixed in the future - I don't know what the intended behavior is.
- I'm unclear on whether the resulting credential object works as intended.
  For instance, `$Credential.GetNetworkCredential()` fails in the absence of a username.